# Have filled in my character sheet properly?

Tags: dnd-5e, player-characters

This is the second character I've ever made and I was hoping that I could get someone to check it over, to make sure it was done right.
It may not be what you'd choose as your class or race, but I just want to know if I filled it out properly.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs in a forum and doesn't fit into the scope of RPG SE.

Comment: Do you mean as in, is it mechanically done right? (Rather than down to opinion-based)

Comment: Hi @Jeff D  Welcome to RPG SE you can find information here [help]. Your question if more suited to a forum. as mentioned above. You can look up and ask questions about how to optimise a character though. There are many questions about this already, just use the search and you'll find plenty of helpful information. :)  Have fun with your new character.

Comment: @ETgothome this question is clearly not about optimisation

Comment: Relevant: [How do I create a D&D character correctly as a total newbie](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/67032/how-do-i-create-a-dd-character-correctly-as-a-total-newbie) and [How do I calculate my skill modifier?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/83930/how-do-i-calculate-my-skill-modifier)

Answer (score 5):

## Numbers

- Your dexterity modifier should be +2, not +1.
- Your AC should be 13 (15 while wearing the shield), not 12.
- Your initiative should be +2, not blank
- Your saving throws should be modifiers, both should be +4.
- Your passive perception should be a flat 14, not a +14 modifier.
- You should have 5 gold, not 15.

## Race

- It's unclear what kind of gnome you are (rock/forest/etc).
- you haven't listed the all the racial traits of you rock/forest/etc gnome.

## Equipment:

- A shortsword should be either a simple melee weapon or scimitar.
- You haven't listed your explorer's pack. It containst a lot of useful stuff.
- You haven't listed some fluff items from your background.
- Your DM might require you to track the weight of your equipment.

## Background

- Your background grants you 2 more skills, so you should have 4 total.
- You should know 1 more language from your background.
- You have not listed your tool proficiencies, moreover:

  - both your class and background grant you proficiency with the herbalism kit, but you are allowed to change the tool proficiency from your background to a different tool or another language.

I'm assuming you are tracking your spells on a different page.

Answer (score 3):

### Some things are missing.

#### Race

It's not clear what type of [gnome](https://www.dndbeyond.com/races/gnome) this character is. Based on your ability scores, it seems to be either Forest Gnome (+2 Intelligence, +1 Dexterity) or Rock Gnome (+2 Intelligence, +1 Constitution). This choice should grant racial traits in addition to Darkvision and Gnome Cunning.

Either would suggest that your ability scores used the Standard Array (15, 14, 13, 12, 10, 8) which is usually what the Players Handbook specifies.

#### Background

Characters start with a background at first level, which grants them extra skill proficiencies, and possibly extra languages, items, or tool proficiency.  This sheet only shows 2 skill proficiencies (presumably from your class) and is missing bonds/flaws, so it looks like you didn't pick a background.

#### Dexterity, AC, and Initiative

Each ability score has a modifier value, which is added to d20 rolls.  The modifier is calculated as half the ability score, rounded down, minus 5.  Your Dexterity modifier is wrong; 14 Dexterity means your character has a Dexterity modifier of +2, not +1. Your initiative bonus equals this value.  And if they're wearing leather armor, then your AC is also incorrect.

#### Passive Perception

A character's [passive perception](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#PassiveChecks) is a static value, not a modifier to a d20 roll. Your character's passive perception would be 12, or 14 if they are proficient in Wisdom (Perception).

#### Saving Throws

[Saving throws](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/using-ability-scores#SavingThrows) are modifiers to d20 rolls, and are calculated as the ability score modifier + your proficiency bonus (+2).

- With 14 Intelligence, your Intelligence modifier is +2, so your Intelligence saving throw is +4.
- With 15 Wisdom, your Wisdom modifier is +2, so your Wisdom saving throw is +4.