# I'm looking to Make my first D&D character

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation

I'm looking to build my first D&D character - a Dragon Born Eldritch knight with White dragon ancestry.  I am not sure what my build should look like.
I pretty much just picked up the player's handbook a few hours ago so any pointers would be appreciated

Comment: This is too broad too work on this site, unfortunately. If you come back with *specific* issues we'll be able to help you, but for now it just sounds like you need to chat with someone about this which done better at a [forum](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5449/52137) and/or our own [chat]. I've given you an upvote to help you across the 20 rep barrier for said chat, but we will be closing this question. No hard feeling though.

Comment: On that note, Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already and see the [help] or ask us here in the comments (use @ to ping someone) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: This related question may help you: [How do I create a D&D character correctly as a total newbie?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/67032/35259)